# Is it possible to create a Python list and fake populating it?

Tags: python, neo4j

I am working with Neo4j graph database, and would like to adapt one of the current REST libraries. Imagine a case with a database with 20 nodes.

```
>>> db = Database("http://localhost:7474")
```

I would like the API to be as simple as possible, so that it would be possible to get the 14th node with something similar to this:

```
>>> db[14]
```

In Neo4j, every node has a numeric key. This means that `db[14]` maps very nicely to `http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/14` However, I don't want to load every node from the database into the `db` object. My preferred behaviour is to lookup node 14, and raise an IndexError if the value doesn't exist in the database. That is, I want the `db` object to be empty but pretend to have a value.

Is it possible to craft something that looks like a `list`, but behaves significantly differently?

Comment: "My preferred behaviour is to lookup node 14, and raise an IndexError if the value doesn't exist in the database. That is, I want the db object to be empty but pretend to have a value." --- How is that pretending to have a value? You raise indexError, so it doesn't pretend to have a vaule at all...

Comment: Perhaps that is expressed poorly. By pretend to have a value, I mean pretend having something waiting in memory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can write a custom class that implements `__getitem__` and generates a result dynamically.

```
>>> class MyDatabase(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, x):
...         if 10 <= x <= 15:
...             return "foo"
...         else:
...             raise IndexError('key not in database')
...
>>> db = MyDatabase()
>>> db[12]
foo
```

See [Special method names](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/specialnames.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Mark - I assumed it involved overwriting one of the double underscore methods.

Comment: i would add that any builtin python type implements an "interface" which is documented. you can fake almost all builtin types using those functions named `__something__`.

Comment: @ADrien: I don't think "fake" is an appropriate word here. If you create anther type, equally good, it is not "fake".